# Efficient way to perform loops of matrix multiplications

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication, processing-efficiency

I have an implementation that involves multiplying matrices, summing them up, and storing them. It goes like this,

```
A = 0;
b = 0;
for i=1:1225
  ... load A_i operator 
  A_i_obj = load([path_temp,'A_',num2str(i),'.mat']);
  A_i     = (A_i_obj.A);
  % z_i is some variable of size Nx1 that I compute in this loop something like
  % x is some variable of size Nx1 calculated above this loop
  z_i = A_i*x; 
  % I have to perform some operations like these 
  y_i = A_i*(z_i + x);
  A = A + A_i*A_i'
  b = b + A_i*y_i;
end 
% A and b will be used here something like
soln = inv(A)*b;
```

My problem is the large amount of simulation time being consumed by the above code. Even when the operations inside the loop are efficient (let's say ~0.01mins), the entire looped implementation still consumes about ~12-13mins. Can somebody please help me out and suggest an efficient way to do this? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not sure it's going to be possible to make sensible suggestions based on this code snippet - as it's not very realistic.  It loads the same file on every iteration, and you don't do anything with `y_i`.  It would be better if you could make a more realistic example.

Comment: Profile, but please, a [mcve] is nice, but it has to be realistic. This doesn't sum up your problem because the code makes no sense.

Comment: Have a look at [`mapreduce`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/build-effective-algorithms-with-mapreduce.html).

Comment: Hello, I would like to apologize for a poorly written pseudo-code. I have corrected my code to show how I am loading the operators one at a time. I will be more than happy to share further details, but I have to make them available again in some pseudo-code format. 

Thank you and apologies for any confusion!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point of loading the `mat` file in every iteration... load your data only once and outside the for loop. After all, the operation is very time expensive and, more important, once the data is loaded into a variable it doesn't have to be performed anymore.

```
A = 0;
A_i = load('A_i.mat');

for i = 1:1225
    % ...

    y_i = A_i * (z_i + x);
    A = A + A_i * A_i';
end
```

On a side note, you are assigning the output of the `load` function directly to a variable using the following overload:

```
S = load(___) loads data into S, using any of the input arguments in the previous syntax group.
  - If filename is a MAT-file, then S is a structure array.
  - If filename is an ASCII file, then S is a double-precision array containing data from the file.
```

So I suppose your file is in ASCII format, otherwise your `A_i` will not be a matrix but a structure array. Also, don't use the `'` operator to transpose a matrix, but `.'`, since the first one corresponds to the complex conjugate transpose:

```
A = A + A_i * A_i.';
```

Since you omitted a part of the code running inside the loop, I can't do more in order to improve its performance.

Comment: While this could be it, I believe you are optimized badly chosen pseudocode.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I just showed my code as some sort of pseudo-code. I have corrected my code to show how I am loading the operators.

Answer (score 0):

Profile, profile, profile

I would guess that the process of loading the matrices is killing you, but it is hard to say. To get a better idea of which step is killing you, start your code with

```
profile on
```

and end it with

```
profile viewer
```

Then run it again. When the code completes, it will show you the time taken by each call, which will help you figure out where the problem is.